# Using color-filled circles for ggplot legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
TRP_C<-100/(100+650)
FPR_C<-200/(200+650)
C<-data.frame(TPR=TRP_C,FPR=FPR_C)

TRP_D<-120/(120+30)
FPR_D<-350/(350+500)
D<-data.frame(TPR=TRP_D,FPR=FPR_D)


ggplot(NULL, aes(x=FPR, y=TPR)) +
    geom_point(data=C,shape=1,aes(fill="A"),size=4,color="red")+
    geom_point(data=D,shape=1,aes(fill="B"),size=4,color="green")
```

The problem is it gives me a ggplot which the points are not clear on it at all.
I think, if i can make the points filled then it would be more clear in the diagram.

So, **how can i make the legend  ,and points filled?**

Comment: `shape=16` or `shape=19` for filled circles (I think `shape=16` is the default), `shape=21` for circles with a separate border and fill. See `?pch` (scroll down) for other point marker options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shape` (insert value from 21-25) inside `geom_point()` and `scale_fill_manual` for colors.

So your code looks like this

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=FPR, y=TPR)) + 
  geom_point(data=C,shape=21,aes(fill="A"),size=4) +
  geom_point(data=D,shape=21,aes(fill="B"),size=4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green"))
```

And output

[image]